# Rails: Interpolation, Attribute into iFrame Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, attributes, ruby-on-rails-4, interpolation

I have an `video_link` attribute.

When a User creates a Listing he can enter a Code (e.g. **aabbcc**).

I want to render this code inside my iframe link, like so

```
<iframe src="https://mywebsite.com/aabbcc/"></iframe>
```

So i tried

```
<iframe src="https://mywebsite.com/#{@vine.video_link}/"></iframe>
```

But this didn't work,
What am i doing wrong ?

I'm Getting no Error, but if i inspect the iframe on Page, the Interpolation is not rendering. im seeing just #{@vine.video_link}

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the controller action? It's hard to know if the instance variable is just blank. Also, what do you mean by "didn't work"; did it throw an error? If so please show the error as well.

Comment: The one rendering responsible for rendering the line of code (view). Errr, thanks for posting the controller actions. Where is "@listing" assigned?

Comment: I changed it to the Actual Code. @Vine has the video_link attribute. It's a Scaffold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh! I get it... change it to:

```
<iframe src="https://mywebsite.com/<%= @vine.video_link %>/"></iframe>
```

You only need to do interp. like that if it's inside ruby code. In this case you're not escaping a string in ruby, you're just putting it in HTML (view).

Example.

If you were in a controller, let's say and had a string that looked like

```
variable = "<iframe src='https://mywebsite.com/#{@vine.video_link}/'></iframe>"
```

- Edit to correct bad copy/paste job.

Comment: The God among us :) Thanks !